# Setting Up my.cnf and Apache.conf on a Wordpress site with 40K monthly visitors

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache2, my.cnf

Since we are rookies on this, we are having a hard time trying to setup a Wordpress server to support around 200K monthly visiting users.  We have two boxes (details below).

The issue here is when the users start accessing the server, MySQL CPU goes to 149%. Here is a copy of the apache2.conf and the mysql.cnf files. Our MySQL database is InnoDB. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

**1. Apache Server**
**Configuration**
8 GB Memory / 25 GB Disk + 200 GB / Ubuntu 16.04

**apache.conf excerpt**

```
Timeout 40
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500
KeepAliveTimeout 2
```

**2. MySQL Server**
**Configuration**
8 GB Memory / 25 GB Disk + 50 GB / Ubuntu 16.04

**my.cnf file**

```
root@mundo-mysql01-c-2-4gib-nyc3-01:/etc/mysql# cat my.cnf
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 0

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 1024
table_open_cache               = 2048

# MyISAM Settings
max_connections         = 300
key_buffer_size         = 256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
join_buffer_size        = 1M
read_buffer_size        = 1M
sort_buffer_size        = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 32
wait_timeout            = 300
connect_timeout         = 300
tmp_table_size          = 32M
max_heap_table_size     = 128M
max_allowed_packet      = 128M
max_connect_errors      = 10000
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1M
query_cache_limit       = 4M
query_cache_size        = 128M
query_cache_type        = 1
query_prealloc_size     = 65536
query_alloc_block_size  = 131072
low_priority_updates    = 1
max_write_lock_count    = 1

# * InnoDB
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 256M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 2048M
```

Comment: Your queries and code in general might be portly written and not optimized

Comment: Hi Igor... Code and queries are from Wordpress.. Any suggestion on what an stable my.cnf and apache2.conf configuration?